# Boys father as wali

Tags: nikah, zina, parents, wali

Can Girl's father appoint Boy's father as wali in marriage?
Girl's father live far away so he accept and say im agreed in this marriage in the phone.
Does boy's father can do the work of qazi?

Comment: The wali of the bride can appoint an agent (Wakil) to act on his behalf.

Comment: Related topics and questions [Is marriage without a wali for divorcee woman valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23774/is-marriage-without-a-wali-for-a-divorcee-woman-valid/25536#25536) and [Who can be wali and in what order?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39553/who-can-be-wali-and-in-what-order)